# Pass parent class to constructor of another class

Tags: c++, class, parent, decoupling

I have several classes in my application, and I'd like to keep the interaction amongst classes restricted to the base classes. To make this concrete, right now I want to do something like this:

```
    class A
    {
    data 

    public:
       void method();
    };

    class A_child : public A
    {
    //stuff
    };

    class B 
    {
    public:
        B(class A *a);
    };
   class B_child : public B
   {
   public:
        B_child(class A *a);
        B_method(); // does some stuff with data in A and B.
   };
```

Although in actuality each of the classes have separate header files, so there's a lot of includes back and forth...

In the cpp file for A_child I want to be able to use B_child (or B, for that matter). But I don't know how to avoid having to call something like

```
void A_child::method()
{
   // stuff

    B_child *example_B;
    example_B = new B_child(this);
    example_B->B_method();

  // more stuff
}
```

It doesn't have to be

```
example_B = new B_child(this);
```

necessarily, it just has to have some way of passing the parent class of A_child into the constructor of B or B_child.

What I'd like to do is avoid having to define B_child as something like:

```
   class B_child : public B
   {
   public:
        B_child(class A_child *a_child);
        B_method();
   };
```

instead of what I have above, because this seems to imply that B_child has to work with A_child rather than with A. Although this is true, there is nothing in the material that B or B_child work with that require A_child - the data in A, not A_child, suffice.

I am guessing there is a way to do this in C++? Could someone give me an example for how something like this works or a link to a page that might explain how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question here exactly? "How can I make B_child take an A* in the constructor?" If so I don't see what's preventing you.

Comment: `B_child(class A *a);`  What's `class` doing in there?  This is not legal code.  Do you mean `const`?  `B_child(A *a);` is also legal.

Comment: @MattPhillips, It's just like `struct A *a` (so basically C). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c6161d161a16b1ba1868dceb5edf95ab-5bfb4a3ecda91a191e93557cbeaa6247

Comment: @chris Okay thanks I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If the `B_child` constructor takes an `A *`, you can pass an `A_child *` to it, since `A_child` "is-an" `A` (via public inheritance).  Did you try doing this and encounter an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `parent` field in `A` class:

```
class A {
  B_child* parent;
public:
  void setParent(B_child* p) {
    parent = p;
  }
}
```

next in `B_child` constructor:

```
B_child::B_child(A* a) {
  // stuff
  a->setParent(this);
}
```

then you access the `parent` object inside `A_child` method:

```
void A_child::method() {
  if(parent)
    parent->B_method();
}
```